# Wait for exchange server update to complete

Tags: vba, events, outlook, synchronization

I have an Outlook VBA script that is moving emails from one Exchange server to another.

After each mail is moved, the Outlook status bar starts displaying "Updating Account@Server.com" or "Updating Inbox". Eventually it displays "All folders are up to date."

Is there an Outlook VBA event associated with the end of this "Updating" process? I.e. is there an event that fires when it next displays "All folders are up to date"?

It seems to be independent of the Outlook Send & Receive process, for which the end is notified with this event: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject.syncend

Answer (score 1):

There is no other event for the sync complete action in Outlook.

The `SyncObject` allows users to synchronize Microsoft Outlook folders, address books, and folder home pages for offline use. The best what you can do is to subscribe to the [SyncEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject.syncend) event of each `SyncObject` instance.